# R Type Checking

Tags: r, histogram, typechecking

I have yet another R question. I am trying to do some type checking, but cannot exactly figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am trying to create a histogram for each level of y. So for instance, I want to create overlaying histograms of the iris data species and their sepal widths, etc

Here is what I have thus far:

```
    #if x isn't numeric
    if(!is.numeric(x)){
    #if y isn't a factor
    }else if(!is.factor(y)){
    #if the length of x isn't equal to y
    }else if(nChar(x) != nChar(y)){
    #error message
    stop('x is not numeric/y is not a factor/both x and y are the same                  length')
}
#otherwise create histogram
#testing with iris data set
hist(y, main = "Iris Species", xlab = "Sepal Width", col = "orange", border   ="blue")
```

Comment: what is exactly your question ? For now, I can just say that I don't know the function `nChar` (is it from a package ?) and I'm guessing you rather want to use `length`

Comment: Some crucial parts seem to be missing from your code. What does "doing wrong" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually use `stopifnot()` for this, so that you check the simplest condition first then proceed to the more complex; you don't want to test all of them at once if the first one is invalid:

```
stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
stopifnot(is.factor(y))
stopifnot(length(x) == length(y))
```

Alternatively, doing all of this in one go:

```
if(!(is.numeric(x) && is.factor(y) && length(x)==length(y))){
    stop("your error message")
}
```

Now it's not clear to me why you're testing `y` here at all, as there is no 'y' argument to `hist()`. Perhaps you were planning to plot separate histograms for `x` for each level of `y`?

If so, you should be able to adapt the following:

```
x <- iris$Sepal.Width
y <- iris$Species
l1 <- length(levels(y))
## temporarily change plotting parameters
op <- par(mfrow = c(1, l1))
for (i in 1:l1){
    hist(x[y == levels(y)[i]],
         main=paste0("Iris Species: ", levels(y)[i]),
         xlab = "Sepal Width",
         col="orange",
         border="blue")
}
par(op)
```

giving:

[image]

I am not aware of an `nChar` function in R; `length()` is normally used for this.

Here's the overlapping approach. Note that `for` loops are often easier to read than `apply` and the loss in speed is likely to be relatively small.

```
for (i in 1:l1){
    hist(x[y == levels(y)[i]],
         ## main=paste0("Iris Species: ", levels(y)[i]),
         main="Iris Species: ",
         xlab = "Sepal Width",
         col=i+1,
         add=!(i==1))
}
legend(x=4, y=25, legend=levels(y), fill=1+(1:l1))
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to do:  plot separate histograms for x for each level of y

Comment: I want to overlap them

Comment: I would like to overlap them.

Comment: @Ashley: What do you mean by overlap?

Comment: @AlexA. such as they do here http://www.r-bloggers.com/overlapping-histogram-in-r/       but it does not clearly explain how to do something where I want to create an overlapping histogram of the iris data set. I am trying to , for example, for every species show a histogram of sepal width

Comment: @Ashley: dardisco's histogram code can be easily adapted for that case. Just change the color for each and use `add = TRUE`.

Comment: @AlexA. I am trying to avoid for loops

Comment: @Ashley: Then you can list each `hist` statement separately as is done in the article you linked.

Comment: @AlexA. It returns an error. I apologize as I am used to coding in Java so R is a little difficult for me